# Filter subdocument by datetime

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've the following model

```
var messageSchema   = new Schema({
    creationDate:   { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comment:        { type: String },
    author:         { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }
});
var conversationSchema = new Schema({
    title:          { type: String },
    author:         { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    members:        [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId } ],
    creationDate:   { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    lastUpdate:     { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comments:       [ messageSchema ]
});
```

I want to create two methods to get the comments generated after a date by user or by conversationId.

**By User**

I tried with the following method

```
var query = { 
    members : { $all : [ userId, otherUserId ], "$size" : 2 }
    , comments : { $elemMatch : { creationDate : { $gte: from } } } 
};
```

When there are no comments after the specified date (at from) the method returns [] or null

**By conversationId**

The same happen when I try to get by user id

```
var query = { _id : conversationId
    , comments : { $elemMatch : { creationDate : { $gte: from } } } 
};
```

Is there any way to make the method returns the conversation information with an empty comments?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a couple of problems here, but stepping through them all

In order to get more than a single match "or" none from an array to need the aggregation framework of mapReduce to do this. You could try "projecting" with [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) but this can only return the "first" match. i.e:

```js
{ "a": [1,2,3] }

db.collection.find({ },{ "$elemMatch": { "$gte": 2 } })

{ "a": [2] }
```

So standard projection does not work for this. It can return an "empty" array but it an also only return the "first" that is matched.

Moving along, you also have this in your code:

```js
{ $all : [ userId, otherUserId ], "$site" : 2 }
```

Where `$site` is not a valid operator. I think you mean [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) but there are actuall "two" operators with that name and your intent may not be clear here.

If you mean that the array you are testing must have "only two" elements, then this is the operator for you. If you meant that the matched conversation between the two people had to be equal to both in the match, then `$all` does this anyway so the `$size` becomes redundant in either case unless you don't want anyone else in the conversation.

On to the aggregation problem. You need to "filter" the content of the array in a "non-destructive way" in order to get more than one match or an empty array.

The best approach for this is with modern MongoDB features available from 2.6, which allows the array content to be filtered without processing `$unwind`:

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": {
            "members": { "$all": [userId,otherUserId] }
        }},
        { "$project": {
            "title": 1,
            "author": 1,
            "members": 1,
            "creationDate": 1,
            "lastUpdate": 1,
            "comments": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$comments",
                        "as": "c",
                        "in": { "$cond": [
                            { "$gte": [ "$$c.creationDate", from ] },
                            "$$c",
                            false
                        ]}
                    }},
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
);
```

That uses [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) which can process an expression against each array element. In this case the vallues are tested under the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) ternary to either return the array element where the condition is `true` or otherwise return `false` as the element.

These are then "filtered" by the [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator which essentially compares the resulting array of `$map` to the other array `[false]`. This removes any `false` values from the result array and only leaves matched elements or no elements at all.

An alternate may have been [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) but since your document contains "creationDate" at multiple levels, then this messes with the logic used with it's `$$DESCEND` operator. This rules that action out.

In earlier versions "not destroying" the array needs to be treated with care. So you need to do much the same "filter" of results in order to get the "empty" array you want:

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": {
            "$and": [ 
                { "members": userId },
                { "members": otherUserId }
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$comments" },
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title": { "$first": "$title" },
            "author": { "$first": "$author" },
            "members": { "$first": "$members" },
            "creationDate": { "$first": "$creationDate" },
            "lastUpdate": { "$first": "$lastUpdate" },
            "comments": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gte": [ "$comments.creationDate", from ] },
                        "$comments",
                        false
                    ]
                }
            },
            "matchedSize": { 
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gte": [ "$comments.creationDate", from ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }            
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$comments" },
        { "$match": {
            "$or": [
                { "comments": { "$ne": false } },
                { "matchedSize": 0 }
            ]
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title": { "$first": "$title" },
            "author": { "$first": "$author" },
            "members": { "$first": "$members" },
            "creationDate": { "$first": "$creationDate" },
            "lastUpdate": { "$first": "$lastUpdate" },
            "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }
        }},
        { "$project": {
            "title": 1,
            "author": 1,
            "members": 1,
            "creationDate": 1,
            "lastUpdate": 1,
            "comments": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$comments", [false] ] },
                    { "$const": [] },
                    "$comments"
                ]
            }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
)
```

This does much of the same things, but longer. In order to look at the array content you need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the content. When you [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) back, you look at each element to see if it matches the condition to decide what to return, also keeping a count of the matches.

This is going to put some ( one with `$addToSet` ) `false` results in the array or only an array with the entry `false` where there are no matches. So yo filter these out with [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) but also testing on the matched "count" to see if no matches were found. If no match was found then you don't throw away that item.

Instead you replace the `[false]` arrays with empty arrays in a final [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

So depending on your MongoDB version this is either "fast/easy" or "slow/hard" to process. Compelling reasons to update a version already many years old.

---

### Working example

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/aggtest');

var memberSchema = new Schema({
  name:         { type: String }
});

var messageSchema = new Schema({
  creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  comment:      { type: String },
});

var conversationSchema = new Schema({
  members:      [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId } ],
  comments:     [messageSchema]
});

var Member = mongoose.model( 'Member', memberSchema );
var Conversation = mongoose.model( 'Conversation', conversationSchema );

async.waterfall(
  [
    // Clean
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Member,Conversation],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },
      function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    },

    // add some people
    function(callback) {
      async.map(["bill","ted","fred"],function(name,callback) {
        Member.create({ "name": name },callback);
      },callback);
    },

    // Create a conversation
    function(names,callback) {
      var conv = new Conversation();
      names.forEach(function(el) {
        conv.members.push(el._id);
      });

      conv.save(function(err,conv) {
        callback(err,conv,names)
      });
    },

    // add some comments
    function(conv,names,callback) {
      async.eachSeries(names,function(name,callback) {
        Conversation.update(
          { "_id": conv._id },
          { "$push": { "comments": { "comment": name.name } } },
          callback
        );
      },function(err) {
        callback(err,names);
      });
    },

    function(names,callback) {
      Conversation.findOne({},function(err,conv) {
        callback(err,names,conv.comments[1].creationDate);
      });
    },

    function(names,from,callback) {
      var ids = names.map(function(el) {
        return el._id
      });

      var pipeline = [
        { "$match": {
          "$and": [
            { "members": ids[0] },
            { "members": ids[1] }
          ]
        }},
        { "$project": {
          "members": 1,
          "comments": {
            "$setDifference": [
              { "$map": {
                "input": "$comments",
                "as": "c",
                "in": { "$cond": [
                  { "$gte": [ "$$c.creationDate", from ] },
                  "$$c",
                  false
                ]}
              }},
              [false]
            ]
          }
        }}
      ];

      //console.log(JSON.stringify(pipeline, undefined, 2 ));

      Conversation.aggregate(
        pipeline,
        function(err,result) {
          if(err) throw err;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2 ));
          callback(err);
        }
      )
    }


  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    process.exit();
  }
);
```

Which produces this output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "55a63133dcbf671918b51a93",
    "comments": [
      {
        "comment": "ted",
        "_id": "55a63133dcbf671918b51a95",
        "creationDate": "2015-07-15T10:08:51.217Z"
      },
      {
        "comment": "fred",
        "_id": "55a63133dcbf671918b51a96",
        "creationDate": "2015-07-15T10:08:51.220Z"
      }
    ],
    "members": [
      "55a63133dcbf671918b51a90",
      "55a63133dcbf671918b51a91",
      "55a63133dcbf671918b51a92"
    ]
  }
]
```

Note the "comments" only contain the last two entries which are "greater than or equal" to the date which was used as input ( being the date from the second comment ).

Comment: Hi Blakes Seven, thanks a lot for you explanation. I have Mongo 2.6.3, but when I try to apply your first propossal the next exception is raised: {"name":"MongoError","errmsg":"exception: field inclusion is not allowed inside of $expressions","code":16420,"ok":0}

Comment: @IvánPeralta You must be typing something different to what is listed here. Everything as I have listed is valid.

Comment: I didn't, just changed Model by Conversation, and the error is {"name":"MongoError","errmsg":"exception: field inclusion is not allowed inside of $expressions","code":16420,"ok":0} v2.6.3

Comment: @IvánPeralta I don't see any syntax errors above, which can be the only cause. I'll try to write out a sample and run it through to prove it.

Comment: Thank you Blakes, BTW: In my integration tests, when I used $elemMatch I receive the whole list of comments, not just the first. It works as expected, the problem is when no comments match with the criteria. Thanks any way Blakes

Comment: @IvánPeralta There you go, perfect working example ( with cut down fields ) and output.